# Function Not Outputting Stack of Boxes in Javascript on Browser

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to create a stack of 16 boxes. I don't think I have the `makeBox()` function in the right place.

```js
let makeBox = function() {
  let box = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(box);
  box.style.width = '28px';
  box.style.height = '28px';
  box.style.border = '1px solid black';
  return box;
};

let makeGrid = function(numberOfRows) {
  let y = 0;
  let x = 0;

  while (y < numberOfRows) {
    x = 0;
    while (x < numberOfRows) {
      x = x + 1;
    }
    y = y + 1;
  }

  makeBox();

};

makeGrid(16);
```

I'm just getting one box in the browser. If anyone has any experience with this, if they could please help.

Comment: Your call to `makeBox` is outside your loop which is why you're only getting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a grid of boxes [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) can help. It saves effort on creating nested loops. Just loop from 0 to the number passed in as the argument multiplied that same number, and create a box on each iteration. Then add it to the element that's been set up to control the grid.

I would also use a class for the box too.

```js
function makeBox(x) {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.classList.add('box');
  box.textContent = x;
  return box;
};

// The grid will be the argument (a number)
// multiplied by that number again, so you just need
// to loop from 0 to that number
function makeGrid(n) {
  
  const grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
  
  for (let x = 0; x < n * n; x++) {
    grid.appendChild(makeBox(x));
  }

};

makeGrid(16);
```

```css
#grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr); gap: 2px; }
.box { width: 28px; height: 28px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```